# c++ forcing operator == overload from interface abstract class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, abstract-class

using an interface (abstract class) on c++ i have the need to force any class than inherits the interface to implement the operator ==.
consider this situation:

```
class IBase
{
   virtual void someFunc() const = 0; 
}

class CInheritClass : public IBase
{
   virtual void someFunc() const; 
   virtual bool operator== ( const CInheritClass& obj ) const;
}

void main()
{
  CInheritClass instance;
}
```

class CInheritClass must implement someFunc since it inherits Ibase, implementing `virtual bool operator== ( const CInheritClass& obj ) const;` is not mandatory.
i would like to modify IBase class in a way that any inheritor X will have to implement

```
virtual bool operator== ( const X& obj ) const
```

the following code will works:

```
template<class X>
class IBase
{
   virtual void someFunc() const = 0; 
   virtual bool operator== ( const X& obj ) const = 0;

}

class CInheritClass : public IBase<CInheritClass>
{
   virtual void someFunc() const; 
   virtual bool operator== ( const CInheritClass& obj ) const;
}
```

but i am after a solution that does not use templates cause every class that wishes to implement IBase must inherit IBase with itself as the template class `class X : public IBase<X>` and that is confusing and unclear to any future developer that might have a look on my code.
any idea ?

Comment: Why?  I'm serious -- the reason why you want this will change the answer you get.  How do you intend to use `operator==` and such classes?

Comment: You're defining a family of virtual functions with different parameter types... these won't work with polymorphism.

Comment: The template approach you suggest is fairly common, so I would not classify it as "confusing and unclear" at all so long as it accurately reflects your design goal. I'm not sure why in your example you didn't make the base class version pure virtual, though.

Comment: Owen, by mistake i didnt made it pure virtual. fixed it.
the template approach has several disadvantages. among them the polymorphism issue as Ben suggested. 
Yakk - the reason i need this implementation is cause class CinheritClass eventually is part of a third class that it's implementation requires operator overloading

Comment: I wouldn't call the template approach confusing either; in the .NET world, that interface (called `IComparable<T>`, actually slightly different but the same idea) is one of the core interfaces even implemented by the standard types such as `int`.

Comment: Your solution is actually quite reasonable and not confusing at all. Many developers are familiar with [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), and those who are not should learn it. .NET languages are now using CRTP to specify e.g. `IComparable` interface, in a way very similar to what you have done.

Comment: thanks N.m that really interesting the CRTP concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a pure virtual function declaration

```
virtual bool operator== ( const IBase& obj ) const = 0;
```

A example of implementation :

```
bool CInheritClass ::operator==( const IBase& obj ) const
{
     const CInheritClass *o = dynamic_cast<const CInheritClass*>(&obj);
     if (o == NULL) return false;
     // TODO
}
```

The input type should be the base class, if not you will not be able to do polymorphically call comparison on base objects

For the idea of inherits from a template: warning,  the base class is no longer the same between 2 derived class.
=> The purpose of the base class changed : With template you just share code, force user to implement function and prevent duplicate code between the 2 derived class

It really depend what you are trying to do. It can be a good design, or not...

Comment: He wants to make each subclass comparable to *its own type*, not one particular subclass.

Comment: And clearly the OP is already aware of pure virtual declarations, since he used one in the question.

Comment: Now you're making each subclass comparable to *all* other subclasses.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the == operator ? To be able to compare 2 subclasses ? The implementation shall check the input type of the object

Comment: @benjarobin Not necessarily. Comparisons such as `apple == car` (assume suitable types) are often (but not always) expected to give a compile-time error, as it almost certainly won't be what the programmer intended, while your approach would let it compile but always return `false`.

Comment: will work as long as my base class is polymorphic. once i'll remove it, the dynamic_cast wont work.

Comment: @hvd Not if he using a template for some other unrelated purpose like described in his question

Comment: i guess you are right. i have 2 options: 
1. use your solution as long as my class is polymorphic
2. use my template base solution and keep my virtualness.
thanks for your help.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it was confusing. But I do think the base class will always have at least one virtual function, as that is the point (in this case) of having that base class.

Comment: @Oded Note that this answer checks type errors at runtime rather than compile time, and adds a string comparison overhead to every `operator==` call (`dyanmic_cast`'s cost basically boils down to a decorated string comparison in certain cases).

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI, the template version is commonly called the "Barton-Nackman trick:"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick

If you want your derived classes to only be comparable to other objects of their own type (and not of the abstract base type), then that is the "trick" to use, IMO.

EDIT: This is similar to the way that Java implements the Comparable interface, so it's not as if (good) programmers won't know what's going on:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down what you're asking for here. You want to force each child to implement an `operator==` with a right-hand side of its own type. But you're also asking that said operator be made virtual. Since the parameter type of each child operator will be different from that of the parent virtual method all you'll end up dong is HIDING the base class operator. Thus you'll never be able to call it polymorphically and the virtuality of the comparison won't be useful at all.

Instead what I would suggest is to just remove the virtualness of the parent operator, and just *use* the `==` where you need to when working with child classes. Then the compiler will tell you when it's missing.

If however you actually need to be able to polymorphically call comparison on base objects you'll most likely have to use something like double dispatch to make sure that both sides access the most-derived type and verify that the most-derived types are the same (otherwise the comparison is meaningless).

EDIT: I don't see anything particularly wrong with the template base class if you really need that functionality - just examine your design and make sure you do need it.

Comment: i get your point. you are correct about the virtualness part. i can remove it. and also remove the operator == from my base class and count on the compiler for errors when a class that does not implement the == is used. it will work, it does work. but i am seeking perfection, and the interface does requires overloading the == operator. in your solution you are asking me to use an interface that does not list all the abstract functions  and once a class wont implement one of the none listed functions an error will be raised somewhere else.it will work. but it is bad practice.

Comment: @Oded No Mark is not correct about the virtualness part. The primary(I actually think it's the solo purpose) purpose of having the interface in the first place is to define behavior - if you remove the == operator from the interface, that implies equality checking is no longer part of the 'behavior contract'. If you change the interface for a micro-level/language-feature-level tweaking, it usually leads to bad designs; in large projects, disasters.